# How to create virtual device?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

I saw tutorials for flutter with android studio, but can't find how to create an android emulator for visual studio I'm using.

I am using flutter with visual studio on ubuntu.

Comment: do you have android studio installed?

Comment: yes, installed today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 Methods that i know of.

### Method 1 (Android Studio)

If you have android studio installed, you can start android studio and add/start a virtual device from avd manager. You can follow this guide to create virtual device.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

### Method 2 (AvdManager Binary)

You can also create virtual devices using `avdmanager` binary. But to use this you need some knowledge with the properties/arguments that it requires.

Example:

```
avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
```

Here's the guide.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager

### Starting The Virtual Device

1. Using Android Studio, pretty strait forward you can use avdmanager.
2. Using `emulator` binary provided with android sdk.

`/PATH_TO_ANDROIDSDK/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 -netdelay none -netspeed full`

`emulator` guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline